# Where can I find omxenc.def?

Tags: font-encodings, installing-fonts, type1, otftotfm, autoinst

I've been trying to locate the files needed to convert OTF files into Type 1, using OT1, T1, TS1, LGR, OML, OMS and OMX encodings.

I located ot1enc.def, t1enc.def, ts1enc.def, omlenc.def and omsenc.def in texmf-dist/tex/latex/base, and lgrenc.def in texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc but there is no omxenc.def.
'tlmgr info omxenc.def' doesn't find any packages containing the file.

Encodings for OT1, T1, TS1, LGR are in texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/fontools. However, I noticed that some .enc files are located in texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base, and named differently to what I expected:

omx.enc = texmext.enc
oml.enc = texmital.enc
oms.enc = texmsym.enc

Does anyone know where to find omxenc.def?, or is the actual name for it different, as happens with the last three .enc files mentioned?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: latex only uses `...enc.def` files for text font encodings as used by `fontenc`. omx is a math symbol encoding

Comment: the dvips  `.enc` files are not related to latex `..enc.def` files. The former are PostScript, the latter are TeX

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for replying. Is there any omxenc.def, then, or am I missing some information here? Is there any font out there that uses OMX, that I can take a look at?

Comment: cmex10  see `texdoc fontenc ` page 10

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I will look into it.